# (2/2) ErrorException Method bsText does not exist

Tags: laravel-collective

Estou usando Laravel 5.4 Chatter Package Forum e Laravel Collective, e me reparei com esse erro

****(2/2) ErrorException
Method bsText does not exist.****

Segui o seguinte procedimento para usar o Laravel Collective no projeto.

ETAPAS PARA USAR LARAVEL COLLECTIVE

0-> Requerir o Collective via console
    composer require laravelcollective/html ^5.4.0

1-> ADICIONAR Aliases

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

2-> ADICIONAR Collective no providder

```
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

3-> Incluir os forms no boot do Form Service Provider depois de criar esse modelo

```
 public function boot()
    {
        Form::component('bsText', 'components.form.text', ['name', 'value' => null, 'attributes' => []]);
        Form::component('bsTextArea', 'components.form.textarea', ['name', 'value' => null, 'attributes' => []]);
        Form::component('bsSubmit', 'components.form.submit', ['value' => 'Submit', 'attributes' => []]);
        Form::component('hidden', 'components.form.hidden', ['name', 'value' => null, 'attributes' => []]);
    }
```

4-> Incluir os componentes na view components/form/
    hidden
    submit
    text
    textarea

5-> Incluir injecao use Form; no FormServiceProvider

Comment: Gostaria de ajuda para resolver esse erro! obr!

Answer (score -1):

`App\Providers\FormServiceProvider::class`,

Essa linha resolveu.